# How to connect external microphone to ASUS laptop with Combo jack

Tags: gnome, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, audio-recording

I am new to the Linux world.I have a headphone with two jacks (Green jack that is for listening and Red  jack that is for microphone). My laptop has one jack (combo jack). When I was in windows OS if I was connect the microphone to laptop the system asked me to choose the mode(for example speaker or headphone or microphone).
I had "Realtek HD audio manager" and this software allowed me to choose my mode.

In linux OS I installed and configured "HDA jack retask".But problem does not solve

I was  spend more that two weeks to solve this problem and I just confused

This is my system informations
Please help me:

Laptop:Asus TP550LJ

Desktop Environment: GNOME

Audio Card: Realtek ALC3236

Answer (score 1):

A $6 hardware solution: Get a 4-pole plug to dual jack adapter cable.

https://www.showmecables.com/headset-mic-breakout-cable-3-5mm-trrs-female-to-dual-3-5mm-trs-stereo-male-6-in

[https://www.amazon.com/KOKKIA-MicAudio_Splitter-microphone-separate-headphone/dp/B01MSU25UK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MSU25UK)

[https://www.amazon.com/Kingtop-Adapter-Tablet-Headsets-Version/dp/B01I3A47I4/ref=asc_df_B01I3A47I4/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I3A47I4)

Comment: Dose not work. I checked but dose not work